# Time Difference in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, momentjs, angular6

I need to show time difference on UI updated every second.

What I tried is:

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { DateUtil } from '../../../framework/Utils/DateUtil';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-time-difference',
  templateUrl: './time-difference.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time-difference.component.scss']
})
export class TimeDifferenceComponent implements OnInit {
  orderTime = '14-09-2018 14:00:00';
  today = new Date();

  clock: Observable<any>;
  timeDifference: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clock = Observable
      .interval(1000)
      .map(() => {
        const orderDate = DateUtil.getDatefromString(this.orderTime, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
        const timeDifference = DateUtil.getDateDiffInHours(orderDate, new Date());
        return timeDifference;
      });

    this.clock.subscribe(
      res => console.log(res)
      );
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<div class="row mt-5 ml-5" style="margin-left:20px;">
    {{clock | async}}
</div>
```

**DateUtil func**

```
static getDateDiffInHours(startDate, endDate)
{
    let start = moment(startDate);
    let end = moment(endDate);
    let diff = moment.duration(end.diff(start));
    let milliSec = diff.milliseconds();
    let dateString = moment(milliSec).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    return moment(dateString, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').toDate();
}
```

Can someone tell me where I made a mistake?

As I am not getting update time difference in UI but I am getting update duration object in Console

Static result on UI

PT10H13M26.992S

Comment: Please create a reproduction on StackBlitz.

Comment: https://angular-uzn3pg.stackblitz.io

Comment: Your reproduction is breaking with an error which is not the same one as you descirbe in your question. The Blitz uses version 6 of Angular while you mention 4.

Comment: What exactly do you get? orderTime never changes, today never changes, so you're recomputing the same difference again and again, which never changes. Also, why do you use `any`? It defeats the whole purpose of using TypeScript.

Comment: getting this as result PT10H13M26.992S

Comment: OK. So that's the time difference. What else do you expect and why? Have you read my previous comment?

Comment: Yes... i am expecting the time difference to be update in UI also

Comment: Why do you thing there should be any update? Again, orderTime never changes, and today never changes. So the time difference between both never changes either. Why do you think it should change?

Comment: but seconds change @JB Nizet..as  i am creating time difference timer

Comment: Where in your code do you think any of the times changes? What do you mean by "seconds change"?

Comment: time difference between orderTime and currentTime is increasing..
i want to show that increasing time in UI..
May i am mistaken some where

Comment: The time that is written on console doesn't come from your `console.log(res)`, I think it is some kind of debug log from the `moment` lib or something like that. You are calculating the difference from two static time instants. Just replace `this.today` with `new Date()` in timeDifference calculation. And read some docs about usage of `moment`.

Comment: i tried, not reached a solution

Comment: *time difference between orderTime and currentTime is increasing* sure. But you never compute the difference between orderTime and currentTime. you're computing the difference between orderTime and today, and today is not the current time. It's a constant value. I've been telling you that 3 times now.

Comment: Ok,, but what is solution..i replaced this.today with new Date() and return date obj instead of duration..

Comment: Well, do what you want to do. Compute the time difference between orderTime and the current time. Remove the `today` field, and use `DateUtil.getDateDiffInHours(orderDate, ne Date());`. That will pass the current time (`new Date()`) every time you compute the difference.

Comment: edited ques... check

Comment: There's no way for the updated code to produce the output you claim to get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180069/discussion-between-coder-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: @Coder, I updated my answer a little bit so that the clock$ observable is only calculated once per tick - no matter how many subscribers (each async pipe is a subscriber)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's not that the view doesn't get updated. If you look closely at what output you get in the console - it's always the same date. The implementation of getting time difference is quite messy and can be done in a better way.

Without any external util functions the implementation can look like following:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {DateUtil} from '../utils/DateUtil';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-time-difference',
  templateUrl: './time-difference.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./time-difference.component.css']
})
export class TimeDifferenceComponent implements OnInit {
  orderTime = '14-09-2018 14:00:00';
  clock: Observable<any>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // order date in millis (can be computed once)
    const orderDate: number = moment(this.orderTime, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').valueOf();
    this.clock = Observable
      .interval(1000)
      .map(() => {
        return Date.now() - orderDate;
      });

    this.clock.subscribe(
      res => console.log(res) // Output difference in millis
    );
  }
}
```

And in the template you could utilise the Angular Date pipe the following way:

```html
<div class="row mt-5 ml-5" style="margin-left:20px;">
    {{(clock | async) | date:'dd HH:mm:ss'}}
</div>
```

In case you want some special date format in the output you could map the clock observable in any way you like. For example:

```js
const orderDate: number = moment(this.orderTime, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss').valueOf();
    this.clock$ = Observable
      .interval(1000)
      .map(() => {
        return Date.now() - orderDate;
      })
      .map((millis: number) => {
        return moment.duration(millis);
      })
      .publishReplay(1).refCount(); // so that calculation is performed once no matter how many subscribers

this.days$ = this.clock$.map(date => date.days());
this.hours$ = this.clock$.map(date => date.hours());
this.minutes$ = this.clock$.map(date => date.minutes());
this.seconds$ = this.clock$.map(date => date.seconds());
```

And in the template:

```html
<ul>
    <li><span id="days">{{days$ | async}}</span>Days</li>
    <li><span id="hours">{{hours$ | async}}</span>Hours</li>
    <li><span id="minutes">{{minutes$ | async}}</span>Minutes</li>
    <li><span id="seconds">{{seconds$ | async}}</span>Seconds</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.